# Why the tmp directory path so unique?

Tags: html, ios

Calling NSTemporaryDirectory(), it will return something like:

/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8E016CC3-4574-40BB-80AB-8714FBF3C069/tmp/

But calling NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSXXXDirectory...) to get the Documents or Library directory path, it will return:

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8E016CC3-4574-40BB-80AB-8714FBF3C069/xxx/...

The tmp path starts with "/private".

And I found that a web page in the wkWebview of an app can only access the resource in tmp path. For example, if I want an IMG element to load a JPG file, then the file must be put in tmp directory. If it is in Documents or other directories, loading will fail.